# In which case the probability of picking up an unknown ticket is higher? When picking up the first or last?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

There are $N$ exam tickets on a table dealt face down. All the tickets are different. There are $i$ students that take the exam. The students enter one by one, and each of them randomly picks up a single ticket to answer and doesn't return it to the table. A particular **student** from  $i$ students (let's call him **S**) knows only $m$ tickets such that $0<m<N$. If **S** enters first, what's the probability that he picks up a ticket he doesn't know? Does that probability change if he enters last among $i$ students.

I was working on this problem for some time and have a solution that goes in the answer. I just want to share the solution I found. Maybe there will be some other more straightforward ways to deal with it.

Comment: No idea what your question is. There are $N$ questions, each student picks one (without replacement). Some student (which one? first, last, any?) gets to pick one of the remaining tickets. Does he get to return it if he doesn't know the answer, or must she keep it regardless? Probability of what outcome, exactly?

Comment: I modified my question. The question is about some student that doesn't know all the tickets. He keeps the ticket regardless. The probability is searched for picking up a ticket that the student doesn't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that the problem can be stated as follows: we have $N$ cards, $m$ of which are red and the remainder black.  The cards are shuffled and dealt face down in a line.  You choose a card at random, but you must not choose one of the first $k$ cards.  What is the probability that the card you have chosen is black?  Let $B$ be the event that the chosen card is black, and $D_k$ the event that it is not one of the first $k$ cards dealt, $0\leq k<n$.  Then we want to compute $\Pr(B|D_k)$.  But $B$ and $D_k$ are independent events; the card doesn't change its color depending on when it is dealt.  Therefore, $$\Pr(B|D_k)=\Pr(B)=\frac{N-m}{N}$$

Comment: I can't see why B and D_k are independent. To make it equivalent to the way that I formulate the problem of the exam, I believe that first k cards should also be also picked up. You don't mention it. I edited the problem, please see the new formulation. I hope, now it is stated clearly.

Comment: @chester1986 It doesn't matter if the first $k$ cards are picked  up or not, so long as you can't choose them.  Of course they're independent.  The probability that any particular card is black is the same.  How does that change when I tell you you can't pick one of the first $7$ cards?  Does it become more likely?  Less likely?  Why?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, they are independent. It is much shorter to think in conditional probabilities, the way you did. And, actually, I didn't notice you had mentioned: "the card doesn't change its color depending on when it is dealt."

Answer (score 0):

The solution is taken from [here](https://www.cyberforum.ru/statistics/thread1719837.html). I translated it and added some details.

---

To start with, let's consider the case of $2$ students. There are $N$ tickets and **S** knows $m$. If **S** enters first the probability of picking up a ticket he doesn't know is $P_1 = \frac{N-m}{N}$.
To find the probability $P_2$ when he enters second, we follow the formula of **total** probability.

​   Now, either the first student picks up a ticket from $m$ (that's the hypothesis $H_1$) with the probability $P\left(H_1\right)=\frac{m}{N}$ or from $N-m$ with the probability $P\left(H_2\right)=\frac{N-m}{N}$.
​   In case that occurs $H_1$ the probability for a to **S** pick up an *unknown* ticket (case $A_1$) is $P\left(A_1|H_1\right)=\frac{N-1-(m-1)}{N-1}=\frac{N-m}{N-1}$.  If $H_2$ occurs, than the corresponding probability is $P\left(A_1|H_2\right)=\frac{N-1-m}{N-1}$.

​   Following the formula of total probability, we should sum the products of the probabilities of hypotheses with corresponding conditional probabilities. That leaves us with

$$P_2 = P\left(H_1\right)P\left(A_1|H_1\right)+P\left(H_2\right)P\left(A_1|H_2\right)=\frac{m}{N}\frac{N-m}{N-1}+\frac{N-m}{N}\frac{N-1-m}{N-1}=\frac{m(N-m)}{N(N-1)}+\frac{(N-m)(N-1-m)}{N(N-1)}=$$

$$\frac{Nm-m^2}{N(N-1)}+\frac{N^2-N-mN-Nm+m+m^2}{N(N-1)}=\frac{Nm-m^2+N^2-N-mN-Nm+m+m^2}{N(N-1)}$$

$$\frac{m+N^2-N-Nm}{N(N-1)}=\frac{-m(N-1)+N(N-1)}{N(N-1)}=\frac{(N-1)(-m+N)}{N(N-1)}=\frac{N-m}{N}.$$

​So, for the case of two students, the probabilities are equal.

---

Now, let's analyse the case of $i\geq2$ students. An event $A_i$ is that **S** enters $i_{th}$ and picks up a ticket he doesn't know. In case $i=1$ (he enters first) $P(A_1) = \frac{N-m}{N}$.

​In case he enters last, $i-1$ students enter before our $i_{th}$ **S**. The total number of tickets that $i-1$ students (each student picks up a single ticket, so total number of picked up tickets is $i-1$) pick up can be greater, equal or smaller than $m$. What we need to do is to find the probabilities that $i-1$ students pick up tickets from $m$. The formula for the probability of the hypothesis $H_j$ that $i-1$ students pick up $j$ tickets from of $m$ is the following:
$$
\begin{equation}
P(H_j)=\frac{C_{m}^{j}C_{N-m}^{i-j-1}}{C_{N}^{i-1}}.
\end{equation}
\label{eq01}
$$
**Explanation:**
    $C_m^j$ - is the number of combinations $j$ out of $m$. This is the number of all possibilities that $j$ tickets are picked up from $m$ by $j$ students

​   Since there are $i-1$ students then $(i-1)-j$ students remain who peak up from $N-m$ number of tickets *unknown* to **S**. Hence, this number is represented by the combinations $(i-1)-j$ out of $N-m$ given by $C_{N-m}^{i-j-1}$.

​   $C_{N}^{i-1}$ is the number of combinations of $i-1$ out of $N$

The formula for $P(H_j)=\frac{C_{m}^{j}C_{N-m}^{i-j-1}}{C_{N}^{i-1}}$ is known as a hypergeometric distribution for $j$.

Next, if $i-1$ students had entered than $N-(i-1)=N-i+1$ tickets are left. They picked up $j$ tickets from $m$, so $m-j$ *known* tickets are left for **S**. In turn, this means that
$N-i+1-(m-j) = N-i+1-m+j$ *unknown* tickets are left for **S**. So, for **S** the probability of picking up an *unknown* ticket is $\frac{N-i+1-m+j}{N-i+1}$.

​Next, obviously, $j\leq m$ and we need to consider all the possibilities of number $j$.  A summation arises on all possible $j$-s. Can be that $i-1\leq m$ and, obviously, $i-1$ students cannot pick up more than $m$ from *known* tickets. This leaves us with the summation up to $\min\left(i-1,m\right)$. The formula of total probability is:

$P\left(A_i\right)=\Sigma_{j=0}^{\min\left(i-1,m\right)}P(H_j)\frac{N-i+1-m+j}{N-i+1}=\Sigma_{j=0}^{\min\left(i-1,m\right)}\frac{C_{m}^{j}C_{N-m}^{i-j-1}}{C_{N}^{i-1}}\frac{N-i+1-m+j}{N-i+1}=$

---

**We will use the formula**

$C_n^k = \frac{n}{n-k}C_{n-1}^k$

---

$=\Sigma_{j=0}^{\min\left(i-1,m\right)}\frac{C_{m}^{j}C_{N-m-1}^{i-j-1}\frac{N-m}{N-m-i+j+1}}{C_{N-1}^{i-1}\frac{N}{N-i+1}}\frac{N-i+1-m+j}{N-i+1}=\Sigma_{j=0}^{\min\left(i-1,m\right)}\frac{C_{m}^{j}C_{N-m-1}^{i-j-1}}{C_{N-1}^{i-1}}\frac{N-m}{N}=\frac{N-m}{N}\Sigma_{j=0}^{\min\left(i-1,m\right)}\frac{C_{m}^{j}C_{N-m-1}^{i-j-1}}{C_{N-1}^{i-1}}$.

The sum $\Sigma_{j=0}^{\min\left(i-1,m\right)}\frac{C_{m}^{j}C_{N-m-1}^{i-j-1}}{C_{N-1}^{i-1}}=1$, as it contains all the probabilities for the numbers of tickets ($j$) that $i-1$ students can pick up from $m$ *known* tickets if there are in total $N-1$ tickets. Note that since $N\geq i$ similarly $N-1\geq i-1$. Thus, "more students than tickets" case is ruled out even if now the summation goes to $N-1$.

Finally, $P\left(A_i\right)=1$.

---

**PS**

Some examples to make clear the formula $P(H_j)=\frac{C_{m}^{j}C_{N-m}^{i-j-1}}{C_{N}^{i-1}}$

Let's suppose there are $10$ tickets, $5$ students and **S** knows $3$. Those $4$ students before or **S** can pick up from $3$ known tickets and the sum of all probabilities is:

$\frac{C_{3}^{0}C_{10-3}^{4-0}}{C_{10}^{4}}+\frac{C_{3}^{1}C_{10-3}^{4-1}}{C_{10}^{4}}+\frac{C_{3}^{2}C_{10-3}^{4-2}}{C_{10}^{4}}+\frac{C_{3}^{3}C_{10-3}^{4-3}}{C_{10}^{4}}=1$.

Let's suppose there are $10$ tickets, $5$ students and **S** knows $7$. Those $4$ students before **S** can pick up from $4$ *known* tickets (exactly the number of students) since $4<7$ and the sum of all probabilities is:

$\frac{C_{7}^{0}C_{10-7}^{4-0}}{C_{10}^{4}}+\frac{C_{7}^{1}C_{10-7}^{4-1}}{C_{10}^{4}}+\frac{C_{7}^{2}C_{10-7}^{4-2}}{C_{10}^{4}}+\frac{C_{7}^{3}C_{10-7}^{4-3}}{C_{10}^{4}}+\frac{C_{7}^{4}C_{10-7}^{4-4}}{C_{10}^{4}}=1$.

Comment: It doesn't matter when he picks.  The probability is always $\frac{N-m}{N}$.  Is that what you got?

Comment: Yes. But I wanted to see a shorter solution.